# UPDATED: Can TMS-convention XYZ Tiles be displayed in QGIS 3.4?

Tags: qgis, tile-map-service

*Updated after having tested in QGIS 3.4*

**Core question:** Is there a way to properly display TMS-convention XYZ Tiles in QGIS 3.4?

If I try to display a "normal" XYZ tileset (like a Stamen set) and a "TMS" XYZ tileset in QGIS 3.2 using XYZ tiles, I get momentarily encouraged at zoom 0:

[image: XYZ and TMS layers at zoom 0]

But any other zoom looks wrong:

[image: XYZ and TMS layers at zoom 0]

Both tilesets look fine in Leaflet because in Leaflet I'm able to denote `tms: true` when adding the TMS layer:

[image: Leaflet displaying both layers nicely]

This all makes sense because the TMS convention has the `Y` inverted (as compared to the "normal" XYZ convention).

Is there a way to properly display TMS-convention XYZ Tiles in QGIS 3.4?

Comment: For some users, this use case may be resolvable by using the Quick Map Services plugin, which allows one to add TMS tile sets. This doesn't help me in particular because some of the the tile sets I need to work with are not able to be added to a public registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* a way to do this, and if you linger the cursor over the URL field, you'll see it's documented in the tooltip.

You can invert the Y axis by entering `-y`, therefore it's like this for a TMS convention tile set:

`../{z}/{x}/{-y}.png`

This comes from https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20302#note-4 thanks to Alessandro Pasotti over on the QGIS issue I filed.

Comment: Please mark your answer as solved. :)